# WebLogic Web Services URL/protocol at run-time

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I've been looking through the WebLogic API and can't seem to find what I'm looking for... Is there a way to determine at run-time the URL being used by an application to access a web service?  I have a requirement to log the URL/protocol that was used on every incoming request to the server.

Any insight is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Kal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work on Weblogic (servlet container).

You need to get the `HttpServletRequest` and you can access any of the methods of [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

I've used a JAX-RS example via the `@Context`, but the principle should be the same for your web service call.

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String showFullURL(@Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {
   return hsr.getRequestURL();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how this would work.  I'd like to do the logging in a handler (filter) before the actual service is invoked.  Also, I can't find an equivalent of getRequestURL in the message context.  It doesn't seem to have the same methods as an HttpServletRequest.

Comment: For accessing methods via message context see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133436/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-httpservletrequest-object-when-using-java-web-service.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was able to get exactly what I needed from your example and the link you gave me.  Thanks again!