# Spring-enabled JAX-WS Web Service how to get client ip

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring 3.1 SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter to publish a webservice like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter" >
    <property name="baseAddress" value="http://192.168.1.8:8888/" /></bean>
    <bean id="webServiceEndpoint" class="com.test.remoting.jaxws.WebServiceEndpoint">
</bean>
```

then I try go get client ip, but my request is null, please tell me is there anythings wrong? thanks very much!!

```
@Resource  
WebServiceContext wsContext; 

@WebMethod
public String Test(){
    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); //here is always null
    return "aa";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private String getIP(){
    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpExchange exchange = (HttpExchange)mc.get("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.http.exchange");
    System.out.print(exchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    return exchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
}
```

Comment: Does this rely on the SUN JDK, what if the application is running on OpenJDK ?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my standalone application running on Jetty, HttpExchange is null.

Answer (score 0):

If the *MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST* or *HttpExchange* don't work. You can use a j2e filter or RequestListener

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/139169/2257772

Comment: Bounty awarded since it's ending, however I still have to try this out. Thanks.